# .NET OAuth library specifically designed to work against Twitter

Tags: oauth, dotnetopenauth, twitter-oauth

Is there a .NET OAuth library specifically designed to work against Twitter? Maybe even something to support MVC? A base controller maybe.....

I am currently using DotNetOpenAuth; it works well enough but seems overkill, in some places too complex and based on documentation more focused on openid.

Comment: This is my view as well. All the libraries I've found seem like way more than I could ever need or want. Unfortunately OAuth seems complicated enough to where I'd need to spend more time than I have available now in order to implement my own.

Comment: I agree - the available options seemed waaay too complicated. So I wrote one - 700 lines including comments. Simple to use. http://cropperplugins.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/65333#1710422  See also, this Stackoverflow answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4002847/oauth-with-verification-in-net/4463378#4463378

Comment: Wow, i couldn't agree more.  I have been playing around with just using OAuth 2 with existing providers, clients, etc. to figure out whats going on with DOTNETOPENAUTH - seems WAY too complicated for what it actually does and is very much OpenID focused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, several in fact.  LinqToTwitter and TweetSharp are both .NET free libraries for calling into Twitter.  DotNetOpenAuth has a longer history in OpenID than OAuth, but OAuth is very much a first class scenario for DotNetOpenAuth.  That said, DotNetOpenAuth is strictly a protocol-level library, so higher-level libraries make calling Twitter much easier and I would highly recommend one of those.