# How to use API key with Yahoo's YQL?

Tags: api, sharepoint, yql

I'm using this YQL command to access stock quote information in an XML format.  The problem is it keeps timing out and rejecting after a bunch of hits.  I think I need to plug in my API key so it doesn't think it's bots.

I'm using SharePoint to process the XML.

```
http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20(%22AAPL%22)&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys
```

This is what it says for limits.

```
Per application limit (identified by your Access Key): 100,000 calls per day.
Per IP limits: /v1/public/: 1,000 calls per hour; /v1/yql/: 10,000 calls per hour.
```

I'm trying to get that per application limit of 100,000 calls per day.  Or I guess that 10,000 calls per hour is also good.  Any suggestions?  Thanks for any help.

Comment: YQL uses OAuth, you will need to create an access key (http://developer.yahoo.com/dashboard/createKey.html).

Comment: I have the access key just don't know what to do with it or where to put it. thanks.

Comment: Hi - I know this is an old post but wondering if a solutions was found using javascript / jquery ? I've also hit yahoo's data limit, but cant find how to use the consumer key.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use OAuth and go through the complicated procedure of exchanging tokens. Once you have an `access_token` and a `token_secret`, you can use them to make authenticated requests until they expire.

The full workflow is summarized [here](http://developer.yahoo.com/oauth/guide/oauth-auth-flow.html).

You'll need to go through the step-by-step procedure outlined in the link above, but essentially what you'll be doing is:

1. Get a request_token from [here](https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth/v2/get_request_token).
2. Redirect user to a Yahoo authorization page.
3. Retrieve the `oauth_verifier` that comes in the query string when the user is redirected back to your page.
4. Exchange the `request_token` and `oauth_verifier` for an `access_token` and `token_secret`.
5. You can then use the `access_token` and `token_secret` to make authenticated requests.

Since you're using .Net, you can make your life easier by using this sample code posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4463378/188740).

Answer (score 0):

hope you have used Yahoo.inc to get your access token 
so just use

```
    $session = YahooSession::requireSession(CONSUMER_KEY,CONSUMER_SECRET, APP_ID);
    $mails=$session->query('your query  limit 10');
```

after feting access