# OAuth authentication without browser

Tags: c#, oauth, oauth-2.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [OAuth with Verification in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4002847/oauth-with-verification-in-net)

I'm wondering if it's possible to authenticate using OAuth without a browser in a C# desktop application. I don't want to show a popup for the users.

I found 2 libraries for oauth:
- oauth-dot-net
- DotNetOpenAuth

Does one of these would allow me to do that?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Yes, both of those work for what you want. [Check this out](http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/documentation/) for documentation help on DotNetOpenAuth.