# Asp.net MVC 4 + WEB API - Custom authentication token

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I am developing an ASP.NET MVC 4 site on .NET 4.0. I am trying to authenticate the site to a WEB API. Now the site will pass a username and password and the WEB API will authenticate it. If authenticated, the WEB API will return a Token with roles, Time To Live etc. I am looking for a few pointers on this.

1.)How to generate this token?I dont want to use STS or anything else. Even a non fool proof approach would do.
2.)In the MVC side, i have to receive this token and set the current session as authenticated and make sure once TTL is expired i redirect the user to login page? Also in all the WEB API requests i need to send this token.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally you can either generate token and implement its verification logic manually or use some 3rd party tools.

For manual implementation look [here](http://blog.stevienova.com/2008/04/19/oauth-getting-started-with-oauth-in-c-net/) or [here](http://www.hoonzis.com/using-dotnetopenauth-to-create-oauth/) at blog post, it could be a good starting point for you. It's based on http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/csharp/OAuthBase.cs class.

For client side and OAuth concepts you can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4002847/oauth-with-verification-in-net) a good answer.

From 3rd parties a goo choice could be [DotNetOpenAuth](http://dotnetopenauth.net/). It's a good library but is complicated when working with OAuth. Try to look at its [Web API OAuth2 sample](https://github.com/DotNetOpenAuth/DotNetOpenAuth/tree/master/samples/OAuth2ProtectedWebApi)

Second questions - answer is yes. You validate token and set request as authenticated. Anyway you can look at Wep API OAuth sample, where it's implemented.

Answer (score 3):

You might consider using the **WebAPI Token Auth Bootstrap Package** I am currently working on - 
available at **[GitHub](http://dgandalf.github.io/WebApiTokenAuthBootstrap)** or **[NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WebApiTokenAuth/)**.

Documentation and code samples available at [**GitHub Wiki**](https://github.com/Dgandalf/WebApiTokenAuthBootstrap/wiki).

> Simple Token and Users Authentication and Authorization Bootstrap for
>   WebAPI applications. Provided with 'TokenAuthApiController' which has
>   built-in support for Login and Logout (cookies-based) and automatic
>   token parsing and authenticating (inside query strings, form data or
>   cookies).

This bootstrap allow you to simply have `[TokenAuthentication]` attribute on actions with the appropriate `AccessLevel`: `Admin`, `User`, `Public` or `Annonymous`.

This bootstrap also provides `TokenAuthApiController` that inherits from the traditional `ApiController` and adds extra functionality detailed **[here](https://github.com/Dgandalf/WebApiTokenAuthBootstrap/wiki/TokenAuthApiController--and-TokenAuthentication-Attribute)**.

*Feel free to Pull requests, Report issues or Contribute*

Answer (score 1):

This would be one of the good places to start, This ties in nicely with the asp.net membership

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7217957/989679

You basically store information in userData of authCookie and works well with WebAPI