# 400 Bad Request: C#

Tags: c#, jquery, http

I am trying to post values to server authenticate method http://***/Token . From my C# client i get 400 Bad request error. While it works fine in jquery.

jQuery Code:

```
$( "#post2").click(function() {
    var Email=$('#Email').val();
    var Password=$('#Password').val();
    $.ajax({
        type:"Post",                    
        url: "http://***/Token",
        data:{
                "grant_type": "password",
                "username": Email,
                "password": Password
            },
        success: function(msg) 
        {
            user=msg["access_token"];
            console.log(JSON.stringify(msg));
        }
    });
});
```

C# code

```
string email = "***@gmail.com";
string password = "***";
var tok = new TokenModel{grant_type = "password", username = email, password = password};
var s = JsonConvert.SerializeObject (tok);

var request = HttpWebRequest.Create (string.Format (@"http://***/Token", ""));
request.ContentType = "application/json";
request.Method = "POST";
using (var writer = new StreamWriter (request.GetRequestStream ())) {
    writer.Write (s);
}

using (HttpWebResponse responses = request.GetResponse () as HttpWebResponse) {

}
```

I also tried by creating local json

```
var x = new
{
    grant_type = "password",
    username = "****@gmail.com",
    password = "***"
};
```

But still the same error.

Is there anything i should do extra for making this call to server from C# client?

Please help,
Thanks

Comment: are you sure, that the object is parsed properly? maybe he gets confused by `password=password`?

Comment: I think i am sure. I have updated the question

Comment: Anyone please help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

```
    public async Task<string> Login(string username, string password)
    {

        HttpWebRequest request = new HttpWebRequest(new Uri(String.Format("{0}Token", "http://***.net/")));
        request.Method = "POST";

        string postString = String.Format("username={0}&password={1}&grant_type=password", HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(username), HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(password));
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postString);
        using (Stream requestStream = await request.GetRequestStreamAsync())
        {
            requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        }

        try
        {
            HttpWebResponse httpResponse =  (HttpWebResponse)(await request.GetResponseAsync());
            string json;
            using (Stream responseStream = httpResponse.GetResponseStream())
            {
                json = new StreamReader(responseStream).ReadToEnd();
                Console.WriteLine(json);
            }
            TokenResponseModel tokenResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TokenResponseModel>(json);
            return tokenResponse.AccessToken;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine ("h..........." + ex);
            //throw new SecurityException("Bad ls", ex);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's `ajax()`'s `data` parameter doesn't contain a json object, but an object which later gets transformed into the post arguments (such as `?var1=foo&var2=bar`).

So try:

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    byte[] response = client.UploadValues("http://***/Token", new NameValueCollection()
    {
        { "grant_type", "password" },
        { "username", "****@gmail.com" },
        { "password", "*****" }
    });
}
```

Comment: I don't know. I couldn't find anything :-(

Comment: I have got this error when exception response is consoled, {"error":"unsupported_grant_type"}

Comment: i gueass then we cant help you. Bad Request is often used by APIs for cases where parameters where missing of having bad values. You should check the Documentation of the service you want to call, as the error message seems to state that `"password"` is not a valid value for the `grant_type` parameter

Comment: Something else is wrong. Then how it works in jquery?

Comment: does the jQuery Call happen on the same server?

Comment: try adding `client.Headers.Add("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");` before `client.UploadValues(..)`

Comment: im afraid im out of ideas too in this case. The last one would be to check wheather there are some unintended whitespaces somewhere in the argument. Sorry i cant help :(

Comment: on the other hand, if you are trying to call use oAuth, have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4002847/oauth-with-verification-in-net