# OAuth in .NET for xing 401

Tags: c#, .net, api, oauth, xing

I´m trying to programming this example for OAuth in C# for the xing api:
[OAuth with Verification in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4002847/oauth-with-verification-in-net)

I get always the error message when i try to get my own user-informations:

> Invalid OAuth signature

Anyone ideas?

Thx

Dennis

Comment: No one have an idea?!

Comment: That could be because of OAuth 2.0 Redirect URL, check what URL you redirect when sending your web-user to Xing.

Answer (score 2):

A few years too late, but I've encountered and solved the issue, so if any one comes back to here:
In GetSignatureBase in the Manager class, you need to change

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this._params[p1.Key]) &&
     !p1.Key.EndsWith("_secret") &&
     !p1.Key.EndsWith("signature"))
    p.Add("oauth_" + p1.Key, p1.Value);
```

to uri encode the value the same way it's encoded in the building of the request:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this._params[p1.Key]) &&
     !p1.Key.EndsWith("_secret") &&
     !p1.Key.EndsWith("signature"))
    p.Add("oauth_" + p1.Key, UrlEncode(p1.Value));
```