# How to call an OAuth API once I have the access_token & refresh_token

Tags: c#, .net, api, oauth

Ok, geesh, I am really having a hard time getting a full understanding of this Oauth stuff.  I am making brutally slow process.

Now, I have the `access_token` and the `refresh_token` and the `id_token`:

```
{
    "access_token":"SlAV32hkKG"
    "id_token":"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9...",
    "token_type":"Bearer",
    "refresh_token":"76c5cdeecfd1543cfd4c3e7c054780ac",
    "expires_in": 3600
}
```

Next, I just need to use the above to make the final, actual API call. PLEASE believe me when I say that I have looked, but I am NOT finding a nice, simple, clean code example of how to make this call in a C# .NET app.

The API I am trying to consume does have their own documentation, and this is all they said about this step:

> **4. Make API Requests**
>
> Now that your application has a valid access token it can now use that
>   token to make authenticated requests to PDK APIs. This is done by
>   simply including the access token in the Bearer type Authorization
>   header of your requests.The Authorization header should look similar
>   to:
>
> Authorization: Bearer
>   eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9...GmUdC2H13YMCwc30Z3l5RCrbwQ

Which is less than helpful from a code writing standpoint.  Are they saying that when I make the final (actual) API call that I do so with no actual authentication, but with the `access_token` included as a normal header? And if so, what is the name (key) of the header?  And is `Authorization: Bearer` it's own header too?

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4002847/oauth-with-verification-in-net) HAS been very helpful, but I'm still having trouble translating his examples into what I'm trying to do.

And because this will be an off-line app, I also need to somehow include the `resresh_token'.

I know that the protocol here on SO is to provide code that we've already tried and ask for suggestions on how to fix it. And normally that's what I do. But honestly, I'm lost here.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Yes, you add it as a header. The `key` is `Authorization` and the `value` is `Bearer your_key_goes_here`.

Comment: irrelevant to this question - i like your bio :)
I like pizza. And mobile development. And .NET. Please send Pizza.
HaHaHaHaHa :)

Comment: yeah still waiting for that pizza :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to set the authorization header using the `access_token`. 
Here is an example:

```
var myUri = new Uri(fullpath);
var request = WebRequest.Create(myUri);
var httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)request;
httpRequest.PreAuthenticate = true;
httpRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + access_token);
httpRequest.Accept = "application/json";

var webResponse = request.GetResponse();
var responseStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
if (responseStream == null) return null;
var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.Default);
var result = reader.ReadToEnd();
responseStream.Close();
webResponse.Close();
```

Comment: when the `access_token` expires, you can use the `refresh_token` to get a new `access_token`

Comment: so is this how the actual call is made? var json = httpRequest.GetResponse();